# if clause in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

i want a simple example of if clause in mysql. i don't want to consider else case,only if clause

Comment: Generally, one gets more helpful answers when the initial post is phrased as a question.  To answer you anyhow, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/if-statement.html .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ex:

```
SELECT *,
       if (`date_last` IS NULL,prev_date,last_date) as date 
FROM `table_name` 
WHERE `id` = 2 
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```